# bash paste command automatically insert newline error

Tags: bash, shell, csv, paste

I am trying to use paste command in bash

paste -d, temp2.csv temp3.csv > $outfile

temp2.csv:

```
a,a,a
b,b,b
c,c,c
```

temp3.csv:

```
1,1
2
3,3,3
```

and the expected result:

```
a,a,a,1,1
b,b,b,2
c,c,c,3,3,3
```

and the real result is like:

```
a,a,a
,1,1
b,b,b
,2
c,c,c
,3,3,3
```

Why are these new lines automatically inserted? I used the same command btw temp1&temp2.csv and it worked perfectly. Is there any problem in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the output as expected.
paste -d, xx yy >> zz

```
➜  ~ cat xx
a,a,a
b,b,b
c,c,c
➜  ~ cat yy
1,1
2
3,3,3
➜  ~ paste -d, xx yy >> zz
➜  ~ cat zz
a,a,a,1,1
b,b,b,2
c,c,c,3,3,3
a,a,a,1,1
b,b,b,2
c,c,c,3,3,3
```